# Flutter(IOS) app concern in the External Link Account API

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I've submitted my app for review on App Store. It got rejected and they replied me with this explanation.

Your "reader" app uses the External Link Account entitlement to link out for account creation and management but does not meet all requirements for using this entitlement.

Specifically, we found that your app does not meet the following requirement(s):

- Your app does not use the External Link Account API to populate the modal sheet before every instance of linking out for account creation and management.

These requirements help protect user privacy and security, prevent scams and fraudulent activity, and maintain the overall quality of the experience when leaving the app to create or manage accounts.

Next Steps

It would be appropriate to revise your app to address the issues identified above. Make sure it meets all other requirements for apps using the External Link Account entitlement before resubmitting for review.

Resources

- Learn more about the StoreKit External Link Account entitlement on Apple Developer.
- Learn more about requirements for "reader" apps in App Store Review Guideline 3.1.3(a).

Requesting help in understanding and resolving this.

I tried every solution and configuration which they have recommended, I resubmitted the app and again got rejected.

On their official website there are two methods: canOpen(popup model for confirmation that you're about leave the app) and open(to open the link in the browser). What they are saying that if your app is redirecting to some link, it should open a confirmation popup model and then on confirmation, it should move forward.

But I didn't understand where these methods are defined or where can I get any sample or demo app.

Comment: You need to implement the interstitial modal with specific text as detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/reader-apps/). There is no method provided for this. You need to implement it as a standard modal presentation.  Apple specifies the formatting and wording that is required.

Comment: "On their official website there are two methods: canOpen(popup model for confirmation that you're about leave the app) and open(to open the link in the browser). What they are saying that if your app is redirecting to some link, it should open a confirmation popup model and then on confirmation, it should move forward.", what about this canOpen() and open() methods?

Comment: First you call `canOpen` - If it returns true then you can show whatever UI component that the user will select to open the external account page.  The UI must appear as a standard link - Underlined in blue.  See the first app screen shot on the page I linked to.  If `canOpen` returns `false` then you cannot show any external link page.  When the user selects the link, then you need to show a modal with the Apple specified content.  This is the second app screenshot on that page.  If they select "Continue" then you open your web site via `open`

Comment: But where these methods are defined? I kind of checked everything and every documentation but I didn't get anything. If I'm using these methods, I'm getting error that these methods are not defined.

Comment: Do you mean `canOpen` and `open`?  For iOS 16 you will need to find or write flutter plugin that access the native StoreKit framework. For earlier versions you need to check `canMakePayments` in StoreKit and create your own modal screen.

Comment: I'm using url_launcher this flutter plugin which provides two methods: canLaunchUrl() for checking the url if it can be launched or not and another is launchUrl() which launches the url.
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://www.google.com/';
  final finalURL = Uri.parse(url);
  try {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(finalURL)) {
      await launchUrl(
        finalURL,
        mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    log('125 ${e.toString()}');
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

In my project, we have a swift file that serves as a delegate to run native code that isn't supported by flutter.

You can register methods that are callable from flutter using FlutterMethodChannel
https://api.flutter.dev/objcdoc/Classes/FlutterMethodChannel.html

Example: (forgive the sloppy code here)
In swift, you can make a method channel available to flutter like this:

```swift
let linkoutApi = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "external_link_account", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
```

And then add methods to it like this:

```swift
linkoutApi.setMethodCallHandler({
       [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result:@escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
       // Note: this method is invoked on the UI thread.
       if call.method == "openLinkout" {
        if #available(iOS 16, *){
          Task{
            do{
               ExternalLinkAccount.open();
            } catch {
              result("oopsie")
            }
          }
        }else{
          result("OS is too old")
        }
       }else{
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        return
       }
   })
```

In flutter, you'll grab your method channel:

```dart
platform = MethodChannel('external_link_account');
```

Then you can use it to call your method

```dart
platform.invokeMethod<string>('openLinkout')
```

This is incomplete because you'll want to make sure you check for whether the user has payment permissions on their device before calling that.

Older os versions use `SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()` I believe and new ones just have that static ExternalLinkAccount.canOpen value. If you call open() without canOpen being true, it will throw an error.

If the user has an os version older than ios16, you'll need to recreate the bottom sheet using the design guidelines here:
https://developer.apple.com/support/reader-apps/
(Download the design guidelines in the Implementing the in-app modal sheet section)

Imports for the swift file:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit
import Flutter
```